# Knowledge Article Version (Knowledge__kav) query returns only articles with the same language as current user

Tags: soql, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I started working with Salesforce Knowledge objects and so far I've been surprised at least 3 times per hour.

The latest issue I'm facing is that I can't seem to be able to query `Knowledge_kav` records for all Knowledge Article Versions (KAVs) independent of their `Language`. The query always returns **only** KAVs of the same language as the user running the query:

[image]

Not even adding **ALL ROWS** to the end of the query returns other languages.

Is there a way to query **all** KAVs independent of their language? Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is en_US (or whatever the users setting is), if you want to retrieve articles in some other language, you will have to specify it in your query

> Always filter on a single value of Language. However, in SOQL, you can filter on more than one Language if there is a filter on Id or KnowledgeArticleId.

[Salesforce Knowledge with SOQL and SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_soql_sosl_intro.htm)

Comment: Thank you. I should have found that documentation myself...